# Multiple Select SQlite and insert

Tags: sqlite, insert

i am tying to insert using union but its not working using sqlite3, any help would be appreciated:

```
INSERT INTO
  eventssubs(eventid,eventname,eventdate,Firstname,LastName,MobileNumber)
SELECT
  eventid,eventname,eventdate FROM events where eventname='my'
UNION
SELECT 
  FirstName,LastName,Number1 FROM Records where id=1
```

its giving [ 3 values for 6 columns ]

Comment: That `UNION` will not work as you want.

Comment: any idea what works ?

Comment: You need all the fields at the same `SELECT` statement. Try using `JOIN`.

Comment: can you give an example please?

Comment: Show me your `events` and `Records` table structure.

Comment: ("eventid" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"EventName" TEXT,"EventDate" TEXT DEFAULT (null) )

 "Records" ("ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  DEFAULT ('0') ,"FirstName" NVARCHAR,"LastName" NVARCHAR,"FatherName" NVARCHAR,"MotherName" NVARCHAR,"School" TEXT DEFAULT (null) ,"DOB" TEXT DEFAULT (null) ,"Email" TEXT,"Number1" TEXT,"Number2" TEXT,"Comments" TEXT)

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO
  eventssubs(eventid,eventname,eventdate,Firstname,LastName,MobileNumber)
SELECT
  eventid,eventname,eventdate, FirstName,LastName,Number1 
FROM events, records
where 
  events.eventname='my' and
  records.id=1
```

Comment: Thank you so much that did the job.